# If a and b are both positive or both negative and a < b , then 1/a > 1/b . Can you prove this without insert number to a and b?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If a and b are both positive or both negative and $a < b$, then $1/a > 1/b$. Can you prove this without insert number to $a$ and $b$, as the following?

Let $a>0$.

Thus, we need to prove that:
$$1>\frac{a}{b}$$ or $$b>a.$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your own thoughts and the effort made thus far, so that people can work with you accordingly. (Please add those in the body of the question instead of commenting.)

Answer (score 4):

Because $$\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}=\frac{b-a}{ab}>0.$$

Answer (score 2):

With

$$a \lt b \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

If $a$ and $b$ are both positive or both negative, then $ab \gt 0$, so you can divide both sides by $ab$ to get

$$\frac{1}{b} \lt \frac{1}{a} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$